# Thread or class for doing nothing until a method is called

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I want to open a tcp socket in java and from time to time call a send-method from other applications.
All that has to be done is waiting until the send method is called and returning the answer to the request. I was wondering if I should use a thread holding the tcp connection and the send/receive method or just a class where I can avoid the "do-nothing-part-until-send-is-called".

Comment: You have to create socket connection(open a server socket then connect it as a client), Then you have to keep socket connection alive by sending pulses. Then you can get that connection to do thing in future

Answer (score 0):

In either case I would create a separate class, perhaps a Singleton or a static class. Then I would call it when I need it.

---

Now if I wanted to make it a thread then it would need to meet some criteria. Should it run parallel to anything else? Will it hold back any other code trying to execute?

Since you are using a [TCP socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) then there might be a good chance that it could hold back execution of other code in perhaps a server you plan to run.

Comment: What is the logic behind the downvote? If you prove that my answer is poor I will gladly delete it. Thanks.